# EXCEL: Check if cell text is found in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of 6500 school courses that I need to "normalize" and the process is to take the exact code (ex: 23.XX510XXX) if that number is contained in a set of defined "rigorous courses" or if it is AP. So the algorithm is like this:

```
if x is contained within X:
then x=x
else if PSO=0:
then x=23
else if (#Observed/PSO) >.5
then x=x
else x=23
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in excel. I tried this:

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$L$1:$L$28,0,FALSE)),23,IF(F2=0,23,IF(G2/F2>0.5,C2,23)))

But it only returns 23 every time. The way it is set up, is column C is the non-normalized number that I check against column L. Column F is the PSO indicator and column G is the #observed.

The PSO and #observed is because we are willing to accept the course overall as rigorous if it was taken as AP more than 50% of the time.

Does anyone see where I went wrong?

If anyone can explain how to do it in VBA (not just give me the code) I'd love you forever!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks almost right but the `VLOOKUP` will always return an error because your "Column Index" is zero, where it should be 1 - try like this

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$L$1:$L$28,1,FALSE)),23,IF(F2=0,23,IF(G2/F2>0.5,C2,23)))`

.....or my preference is for COUNTIF like this

`=IF(COUNTIF($L$1:$L$28,C2)=0,23,IF(F2=0,23,IF(G2/F2>0.5,C2,23)))`

Comment: Neither of those are working for me. Is it because the cells I'm comparing are strings? Both of those codes always return "23". Also I tried the VLOOKUP with a 1 as the column index (I don't actually know what it means, but 1 seemed wiser than 0 at first) and neither worked for me

Comment: It seems like it only works when BOTH conditions are met. So if G2/F2 > .5 and F2 <> 0 AND it is included in the other column then it'll take it, but not if only one condition is met.

Comment: pnuts, how do I overcome that then?

Comment: Perhaps it should be like this: `=IF(COUNTIF($L$1:$L$28,C2),C2,IF(F2=0,23,IF(G2/F2>0.5,C2,23)))`